# Keep the trailing newlines when reading a PEM with yq

Tags: bash, yq

I have the following use case. I need to read from an YAML file using `yq` v4 PEM keys. It's then important to keep the trailing newlines otherwise a future reading of those PEM keys would miserably fail.

I haven't found a way in Bash to read a PEM from an Yaml file and store it in a variable keeping the trailing newlines.

Naturally if I would use `$()` Bash would remove the trailing new lines.

Do you have any other idea?

Comment: `var=$(value)` only strips the _one_ newline at the very end of input. You can just add it back in if you need it.

Comment: ...I suspect you may be testing with `echo $var` instead of `echo "$var"`. Quotes matter.

Comment: (...but a [mre] complete enough to let us see the problem ourselves would do a lot of good to understand the issue)

Comment: (the other thing is that `echo "$var"` puts back the newline that `var=$(value)` stripped, so you end up round-tripping back to your original value and not losing anything on the way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *seriously* doubt that you genuinely need to do this (see comments on the question), but using a process substitution to feed input to the `read` command (configured to expect end-of-input to be signified by a NUL rather than a newline) will work:

```
IFS='' read -r -d '' input < <(yq ... && printf '\0')
```

Be sure you check stored contents with `echo "$input"` or `declare -p input`, not `echo $input`. (That's true in the command-substitution case too).

Comment: Nice +1, with the `&& printf '\0'` you can determine if `yq` returned successfully by testing the return status of `read`

Comment: in my case w/o `&& printf '\0'` it does not work. that must be present.

Comment: Why is `&& printf '\0'` needed, as with `IFS='' read -r -d '' input < <(yq ...)`, `$input` already contains the final newline ?

Comment: @Philippe, but without it the `read` will always have a nonzero exit status.

Comment: @Mazzy, ...I assume you're using `set -e` so any command returning nonzero in an unchecked context causes the script to terminate? If `read` is told to go to the next NUL and never sees a NUL it fails. Note that the definition of "unchecked context" is squirrelly; poorly defined, unintuitive in the details, subject to change between versions; this is part of why I don't recommend anyone use `set -e` ever -- manual error handling is more predictable.

Comment: See also [BashFAQ #105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises) re the "`set -e` is a bad idea" assertion.